# Parallel Tasks Sharing a Global Variable

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Hi I am new to using Parallel tasks. I have a function which I need to run multiple times in parallel. Below is the dummy code to show this,

```
public MyClass GlobalValue;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SaveValue());
    Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SaveValue());
    Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SaveValue());
}

public void SaveValue()
{
    string val = GetValueFromDB();
    if (GlobalValue == NULL)
    {
        GlobalValue = New MyClass(val);
    }
    else if (GlobalValue.Key != val)
    {
        GlobalValue = New MyClass(val);
    }

    string result = GlobalValue.GetData();
}
```

Now the line  GlobalValue = New GlobalValue(val) is called every time. Kindly help me with this. I think there is a problem with the Global Variable.

Comment: I think you have a problem with race conditions and lack of any kind of locking here....

Comment: What is the point of this code?

Comment: You need to write thread-safe code.  Good luck.

Comment: @Rotem It looks like an attempt to 'cache' GlobalValue..

Comment: @NikolayKhil Even with proper locking, this looks like it would be pointless.

Comment: @Rotem. Yep, I know. He can try to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` though.

Comment: It doesn't look like this problem is suited for parallelization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, why not do

```
static void Main()
{
    var tasks = new[]
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => YourFunction()),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => YourFunction()),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => YourFunction())
        };

    Task.WaitAll(tasks)
}

public static string YourFunction()
{
    var yourClass = new MyClass(GetValueFromDB());
    return yourClass.GetData();
}
```

I don't see why you need `GlobalValue`. Is `MyClass` expensive to instantiate? More notably, you don't do anything with the results so all is moot.

---

Since the features are available, assuming you're using .Net 4.5 (c# 5.0), you could do

```
static void Main()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(YourFunction(), YourFunction(), YourFunction());
}

public async Task<string> YourFunction()
{
    return new MyClass(GetValueFromDB()).GetData();
}
```

---

For the sake of illustration, you could still use a global variable but it would massively mitigate the benefits of parallelization. You just have to make sure you serialize access to shared state or use thread safe types that do it for you.

adapted from your example,

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim globalLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1));

...

public void SaveValue()
{
    string val = GetValueFromDB();
    MyClass thisValue;

    globalLock.Wait();
    try
    {
        if (this.GlobalValue == NULL)
        {
            this.GlobalValue = new MyClass(val);
        }
        else if (this.GlobalValue.Key != val)
        {
            this.GlobalValue = new MyClass(val);
        }

        thisValue = this.GlobalValue
    }
    finally
    {
        globalLock.Release();
    }

    string result = thisValue.GetData();
}
```

Comment: In your last block of code you're making a memory lock using an same object that, not only might be null, it can also have its reference pointed to a new instance. This spells disaster. To protect the reference you should use for the lock another object that's guaranteed to never change.

Comment: @mycelo, I believe you are right, I updated that block. Congrats on the archeology.

Answer (score 3):

You need to synchronize the access to the shared data, as each thread will try to access it at the same time, and see that it's null, then all will allocate.

Note that the synchronization, if done via lock, will likely cause the three threads to effectively run sequentially, as only one thread can enter a lock at a time.